# Why do the return type of Typescript Array.map allow violation of interface?

Tags: typescript

I was expecting the below piece of Typescript code to fail with an `is not assignable` error for adding `here` to the `ImyWrapper` interface. However, no error occurs and I would like an explanation.

```
interface ImyItem {
    id: string;
}

interface ImyWrapper {
    item: ImyItem;
}

class Test {
    private itemWrappers: ImyWrapper[] = [];

    bar() {
        const item1: ImyItem = { id: "one" };
        const item2: ImyItem = { id: "two" };
        const items = [item1, item2];

        this.itemWrappers = items.map(item => {
            return { item, here: "why does this not cause error?" };
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the code in [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFsCerLuQbwChkTlgATALmQGcwpQBzAbkIF9DDRJZEUNMAdShwADqOgFipYLmoCcEdKw6EEAGzg0ayACoQ6U0slEMAbnEhlcwsRKg15WW+OgBtALrIAvMk+tpEgAjOCgACgBKI2NSBAB7EENZJQBGJ2xcHwIyKmQAIgSIPOQ2VhjYhKTcACZ0xTxffBzqPLAAdzji0sCY+MSwayUdXzdk9BSAGkH0ao8A8pIwAAtgGgA6MZd7Yen19DEwsZ8APmiF0igIMABXKBBssaml6AgWtqXMZHI4g2Rl1eQIDiAwQcGuNBQ0CgcSgAH4umUFmwIoiSBw2EA)

Comment: I think the duplicate answers it. If you need more info let me know and I can reopen.

Comment: Your call, but the duplicate had a solution, where this answer provides none. The fact structural sub-tying works this way would preclude any excess property checks, and the answer below makes no mention of why that is ever an error.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir you are right. We should somehow amalgamate

Answer (score 2):

Few important things about type compatibility in TypeScript

> Type compatibility in TypeScript is based on structural subtyping.

and

> The basic rule for TypeScript’s structural type system is that x is compatible with y if y has at least the same members as x

It means that we can assign type Y to type X if Y has all needed properties of type X. In other words if Y is superset of X we can assign it to X.

**We can say - if Y structurally extends X then Y is assignable to X**

This exact case exists in your problem.

```
a = { item, here: "why does this not cause error?" }
// a has structure which has a type:
interface ImplicitAType {
   item: ImyItem
   here: string
}

// the wanted structure is
interface ImyWrapper {
    item: ImyItem;
}
// below we can have a prove of that, this evaluates to true
type DoesAExtendsWrapper = ImplicitAType  extends ImyWrapper  ? true : false;
```

So we have proven that the type which you return extends the type you assign, that means - it is fully allowed by the type system, because of structural subtyping language behavior. You can read more here - [Type Compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

You can be strict by strictly defining the output of your mapping function:

```
this.itemWrappers = items.map((item): ImyWrapper => {
            return { item, here: "now it is an error!" };
        });
```

Comment: The `items.map((item: ImyWrapper)` is defining the iterator and not the output?

Comment: @maasha yes sorry, that was a typo. Fixed!